# grunt build does not work for SGJC

Tags: error, commerce-cloud, demandware

I am trying to follow the steps described over [here](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FDWAPI%2Fscriptapi%2Fhtml%2Fapi%2Fclass_dw_util_SeekableIterator.html).

So, I come to the part where I am ready to run the `grunt build` command. And here is the output I am getting after running it:

```
$ grunt build
>> Local Npm module "grunt-sass" not found. Is it installed?

Running "browserify:dev" (browserify) task
>> Bundle app_storefront_core/cartridge/static/default/js/app.js created.

Running "sourcemap" task

Running "sass:dev" (sass) task
WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `black' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "black").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `beige' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #f5f5dc, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "beige").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `blue' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #0000ff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "blue").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `purple' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #800080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "purple").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `red' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ff0000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "red").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `brown' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #a52a2a, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "brown").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `green' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #008000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "green").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `grey' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #808080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "grey").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `pink' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffc0cb, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "pink").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `orange' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffa500, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "orange").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `white' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffffff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "white").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `yellow' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffff00, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "yellow").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `navy' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "navy").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `black' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "black").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `beige' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #f5f5dc, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "beige").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `blue' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #0000ff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "blue").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `purple' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #800080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "purple").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `red' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ff0000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "red").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `brown' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #a52a2a, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "brown").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `green' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #008000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "green").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `grey' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #808080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "grey").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `pink' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffc0cb, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "pink").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `orange' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffa500, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "orange").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `white' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffffff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "white").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `yellow' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffff00, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "yellow").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `navy' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "navy").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `black' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "black").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `beige' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #f5f5dc, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "beige").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `blue' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #0000ff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "blue").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `purple' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #800080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "purple").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `black' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "black").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `red' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ff0000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "red").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `beige' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #f5f5dc, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "beige").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `brown' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #a52a2a, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "brown").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `blue' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #0000ff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "blue").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `green' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #008000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "green").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `purple' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #800080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "purple").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `grey' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #808080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "grey").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `red' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ff0000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "red").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `pink' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffc0cb, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "pink").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `brown' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #a52a2a, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "brown").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `orange' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffa500, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "orange").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `green' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #008000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "green").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `white' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffffff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "white").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `grey' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #808080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "grey").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `yellow' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffff00, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "yellow").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `navy' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "navy").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `pink' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffc0cb, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "pink").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `orange' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffa500, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "orange").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `white' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffffff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "white").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `yellow' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffff00, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "yellow").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `navy' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "navy").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `black' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "black").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `beige' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #f5f5dc, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "beige").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `blue' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #0000ff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "blue").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `purple' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #800080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "purple").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `red' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ff0000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "red").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `brown' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #a52a2a, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "brown").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `green' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #008000, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "green").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `grey' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #808080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "grey").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `pink' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffc0cb, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "pink").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `orange' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffa500, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "orange").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `white' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffffff, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "white").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `yellow' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #ffff00, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "yellow").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

WARNING on line 2, column 10 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_color_swatches.scss:
You probably don't mean to use the color value `navy' in interpolation here.
It may end up represented as #000080, which will likely produce invalid CSS.
Always quote color names when using them as strings (for example, "navy").
If you really want to use the color value here, use `"" + nth($type, 1)'.

... another deprecations go here

DEPRECATION WARNING on line 112 of app_storefront_core/cartridge/scss/default/_multi_inventory.scss:
Extending a compound selector, button.simple, is deprecated and will not be supported in a future release.
Consider "@extend button, .simple" instead.
See http://bit.ly/ExtendCompound for details.


Running "autoprefixer:dev" (autoprefixer) task
>> 5 autoprefixed stylesheets created.

Done, without errors.
```

The result seems to be `Done, without errors.` but at the end when I go to my storefront the styles are not applied and the old version is shown to me:

[image]

I verified that the cache is disabled for the SiteGenesis, also I cleared the cache using Chrome developer tools in **Application** section and Hard Reloaded the page.

But still nothing helps.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the solution is to go to **Project** - **Clean...** in UX Studio or upload the built version in any other way.